# How can I use case sensitive in mysql except the first character of the string?

Tags: mysql, string, character, case

How can I use case sensitive in mysql except the first character of the string?

Examples:

String: `ABC12345`

- `aBC12345`: ok
- `abc12345`: no
- `ABc12345`: no

Answer (score 1):

You can use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html):

```
select * from mytable where binary myfield REGEXP '^[aA]BC12345$';
```

Make note of:

> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results with multibyte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

View a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48a12b/2/0).

Comment: If you're running this query more often than updating the table data, you might be better off setting the column as binary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the binary option as such :

`select * from mytable where binary myfield like '%BC12345'`

Comment: That would make any character(s) acceptable before the case sensitive portion.

Comment: Thank you,

however, the letter "a" is required in the comparison, but does not matter if it is uppercase or lowercase.

You know what I mean?